# Transform 3D Tensor to 4D

Tags: tensorflow

I am using the VGG16 Model, which expects a 4D Tensor as input. When I call `model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, ...)` my `xtrain` is a list of 3D Tensor `[size, size, features]` - so in this case: `[224,224,3]`

What I want is 4D Tensors with `[len(images), size, size, features]`

How could I modify my code to get there?

I tried `tf.expand_dims` and `tf.concant` but it didn't work.

```py
# Transforming my image to a 3D Tensor
image = tf.io.read_file(image)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
image = tf.image.resize(image, [IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE])
image = image / 255.0
```

Error msg after `model.fit`:

> Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (224, 224, 3)

Comment: numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are reading in only a single image and passing that. If that's the case, you can add a dimension of 1 to the first axis of the image. There's lots of ways to do that.

Using [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```py
image = image.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)
```

Using some [fancy numpy slicing notation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to add an axis (personal favorite):

```py
image = image[None, ...]
```

Using [`numpy.expand_dims()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) as explained in Abhijit's answer.

I imagine you want to be reading a bunch of images in though. Possibly an issue with your input process? Can you wrap your read in a loop and read multiple files? Something like:

```py
images = []
for file in image_files:
    image = tf.io.read_file(file)
    # ...
    images.append(image)
images = np.asarray(images)
```

Comment: Yes, it is a snippet of my mapping function - So I reshaped my Image. Does it make sense to add the size of all images to the new expanded dimension? How could I achieve that? (Sorry, TF beginner)

Comment: It only makes sense if you are collecting all images in some object, e.g. `images` in my last example. In general your first dimension is total number of images. If you have a single image, this should be 1. I would just make sure you are reading all of your images into one big object, where iterating over the first axis gives you a new image with each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)`

Comment: OK, does it make sense to fill it with the information of how many images I have? How could I add the information to the expanded dimension?